# Add newlines to a text resource in Android?

Tags: android, layout, dialog, resources, textview

I have a custom `Dialog` that contains only a `TextView` to display some text in my application.  [The documentation](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/resources/faq/commontasks.html#selectingtext) lists that only the `b`, `i`, `u`, `tt`, `big`, `small`, `sup`, `sub`, and `strike` tags are supported.  I really need to add some newlines for readability.  Do I need to change to a more complicated layout, or is there some way to encode newlines in the resource?  I tried adding `br` tags, but that did not help.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

On a lark, I tried adding `\n` to my resource, and happily discovered that it added a newline!  I hope this saves someone else the trouble.

Comment: you can get the resource with the </br> tag and use Html.fromHtml(str), note that you get back a CharSequance and NOT a String.